# How does MediatR know which handler to call?

Tags: c#, mediatr

I'm learning MediatR and I have a problem connecting the Controller to the Handler.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<PersonModel>> Get()
{
    return await _mediator.Send(new GetPersonListQuery());
}
```

My understanding is that the Controller will invoke the Handler using `_mediator.Send()`. However, the argument for Send is not the Handler but the `Command` / `Query`.

In Visual Studio, I checked how many reference there are to the Handler and it says Zero. So how does the MediatR know which particular handler to call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MediatR makes heavy use of generic types in order for its mechanism to work. As you probably noticed from using it, you are required to use certain interfaces *in the right way* in order for your requests and handlers to be usable for MediatR.

Let’s take your example to explain how this all works:

```cs
await _mediator.Send(new GetPersonListQuery());
```

In order for `GetPersonListQuery` to be accepted, it will need to implement the marker interface `IRequest<TResponse>` (where `TResponse` stands for any response type). This also works if your request class implements this interface implicitly, e.g. by implementing `IRequest` instead (which is a shortcut for `IRequest<Unit>`).

So `GetPersonListQuery` implements the request interface which makes it a valid request type for MediatR. In order for a *handler* to be able to respond to it, that handler will now need to implement `IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>` (again, implicitly is also ok).

So you now have this constellation:

```cs
public class GetPersonListQuery : IRequest { }
public class PersonListHandler : IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery> { }
```

From the point of view of **using** MediatR, this is usually all that you will need to do. MediatR will connect these two, so the handler runs when your request is sent.

It does that by relying on dependency injection, most commonly the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` container. The dependency injection container basically works by collecting a list of service registrations that contain both a *service* type and an *implementation* type. When the container then needs to resolve an instance of the service type, it will look up the service registration for that and construct an object by instantiating the implementation type.

In our example, the `PersonListHandler` is the implementation type, and the `IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>` interface is the service type. So when something requests an `IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>` from the DI container, the DI container will respond to it with an instance of `PersonListHandler`.

So MediatR doesn’t actually do that much; in fact, the most of its complexity comes from abstracting the dependency injection container so that it can work with others as well. But if you wanted to implement this with a specific DI container in mind, the implementation could look like this (simplified pseudo-code):

```cs
public Task<object> Send(IRequest request)
{
    var requestType = request.GetType(); // GetPersonListQuery
    var handlerType = CreateHandlerType(requestType); // IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>

    var handler = GetService(handlerType); // PersonListHandler object
    return await handler.Run(request);
}
```

So the magic mostly boils down to the magic from the DI container, with MediatR making use of the container’s ability to resolve services.

But how does the DI container know *which* handlers to register? That is pretty easy to explain: When you do `services.AddMediatR(…)` then you are essentially telling MediatR to actively *scan* the assembly for all types that implement `IRequestHandler<T>` and register those with the dependency injection container. So just by adding a new request handler to your project, `AddMediatR` will pick that up when the application launches, making it available to the DI container and by that to the MediatR mediator implementation.

---

Since MediatR relies on the DI container for resolving the request handlers, this also gives you a direct answer to the other question you had: What happens when you have multiple request handlers for one request type?

The DI container by default will only ever give you *one* instance when resolving a service. This means that when you have multiple handlers implementing `IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>`, you will only get *one* of them. Usually, the DI container will use the *latest* service registration to resolve a service. So if you register two implementation types for the same service type, the later registration will overwrite the former.

As you don’t register the services yourself with `AddMediatR`, you cannot actively control the registration order. Since it’s iterating over all types, I would expect the registration order to be alphabetically, but I wouldn’t rely on that. If you want a specific handler to run, you should just avoid having a different handler in the same assembly.

Note that there are cases where multiple service registrations do work: The whole notification concept in MediatR (`INotification` and `INotificationHandler`) is made for the ability for multiple handlers to exist. This is using a different feature with the dependency injection container which allows you to resolve instances *for all* service registrations. So if you have two handlers for the same notification, both handlers will be returned by the DI container and MediatR can call them both. The rest of the handling in MediatR is really the same as with requests though.

Comment: Great answer.  I understand now.  Thanks very much for the clear and detail explanation !  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is **CreateHandlerType**? I want to try creating the `handlerType` in my code followed by **GetService** to see if I could manually get my handler to run - because I think MediatR is calling the wrong method.

Comment: @podrick That code containing the `CreateHandlerType` is pseudo-code showing how MediatR works internally. This will not help you when trying to use MediatR. If you are using MediatR, then you just need to create the correct types and register them with the dependency injection container.

Comment: Everything is registered. We have about 200 MediatR slices. There are no compile errors, but when I run `var response = _mediator.Send(request);`, the **response** is always NULL - but my *Handler* does not return NULL. How do I troubleshoot that? Should I post a new question?

Comment: poke, I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928299/

Answer (score 3):

At runtime, MediatR scans your project for classes implementing `IRequestHandler<T>` and makes note of each of them (including your `IRequestHandler<GetPersonListQuery>`). When you use `_mediator.Send`, it matches the type of the parameter to a matching `IRequestHandler` it found during app startup.

Comment: So I don't have to explicitly call the handler.  What would happen if it found 2 Handlers with the same signature ?  As program files, they won't know about each other, so it's valid to have 2 with the same signature, probably different namespace, I guess.   When it scans and found 2, then how would it resolve it ?  Thanks very much !

Comment: `"What would happen if it found 2 Handlers with the same signature ?"` - I'd hazard a guess it throws an exception.

Comment: "So I don't have to explicitly call the handler" no its "magic" behind

Answer (score 2):

when you create Query/Command, you use IRequest interface. then in handler you call IRequestHandler<Query/Command>. here they make relation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't understand how would it know to connect them ?    And what happens if I have 2 Handlers containing the same <Query/Command> for example ?

Comment: having two handler with one command/query is not possible.