# How do i fix a Mediatr Handler that has no errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr, mediator

The company I am working with has multiple developers. We are all fairly new to MediatR, and we currently have about 200 "slices" running correctly on our API.

The project is ASP.NET Core with .NET 7.0.

In the API's **Program.cs**, we have `using MediatR;` at the top and NuGet shows we are running Version 12.2.0 by Jimmy Bogard.

```cs
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
{
  cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(Program).Assembly);
  cfg.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationPipelineBehavior<,>));
  cfg.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(TransactionPipelineBehavior<,>));
});
```

I have written a new API on the server called **AddPhoneNumber** that the Web Client hits fine, the request is generated, but the response from `_mediator.Send(request)` is always `NULL` - so it fails.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhoneNumber(long applicantId, string dialNumber, int phoneTypeId)
{
    var request = new AddPhoneNumber.Request()
    {
        ApplicantId = applicantId,
        DialNumber = dialNumber,
        PhoneTypeId = phoneTypeId,
    };
    var response = await _mediator.Send(request);
    return response.PhoneNumberId > 0 ? Ok(response) : NotFound(response);
}
```

But the way I wrote my **Handler**, it should never return a `NULL` value.

The class is below because I may have written something wrong. I have a breakpoint set in Visual Studio 2022 at the method `Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`, but it never even gets called.

```cs
public class AddPhoneNumber
{
    public class Request : IRequest<Response>
    {
        public long ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public string DialNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int PhoneTypeId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Response
    {
        public long PhoneNumberId { get; set; }
    }
 
    #region validators
 
    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Request>, IRequestValidator
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.ApplicantId).GreaterThan(0);
        }
    }
 
    public class Validator2 : AbstractValidator<Request>, IRequestValidator
    {
        public Validator2()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.PhoneTypeId).GreaterThan(0);
            RuleFor(r => r.DialNumber).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        }
    }
 
    public class DomainValidator : AbstractValidator<Request>, IDomainValidator
    {
        public DomainValidator(APIContext db)
        {
            //check Database
            RuleFor(r => r.ApplicantId).MustAsync(async (id, cancellation) =>
            {
                var result = await db.Applicants.FindAsync(id, cancellation);
                return result != null ? true : false;
            }).WithMessage("Applicant is invalid");
            RuleFor(r => r.PhoneTypeId).MustAsync(async (id, cancellation) =>
            {
                var result = true;
                if (id != 0)
                {
                    var lookup = await db.Lookups.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.LookupId == id && !l.IsDeleted, cancellation);
                    result = (lookup != null);
                }
                return result;
            }).WithMessage("Phone Type is invalid");
            RuleFor(r => r.DialNumber).MustAsync(async (obj, id, cancellation) =>
            {
                var result = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.DialNumber))
                {
                    var any = await db.PhoneNumbers.AnyAsync(p =>
                        p.ApplicantId == obj.ApplicantId &&
                        p.PhoneTypeId == obj.PhoneTypeId &&
                        p.DialNumber == obj.DialNumber);
                    result = !any;
                }
                return result;
            }).WithMessage("Phone Number already exists for Applicant");
        }
    }
    #endregion
 
    #region handler
    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Request, Response>
    {
        private readonly APIContext _db;
 
        public Handler(APIContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
 
        public async Task<Response> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = new Response();
            var phoneNumbers = await _db.PhoneNumbers.Where(x => x.ApplicantId == request.ApplicantId).ToListAsync();
            var applicant = await _db.Applicants.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ApplicantId == request.ApplicantId);
            if (applicant != null)
            {
                var exactPhone = phoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DialNumber == request.DialNumber && x.PhoneTypeId == request.PhoneTypeId);
                if (exactPhone != null)
                {
                    response.PhoneNumberId = exactPhone.PhoneNumberId;
                }
                else
                {
                    var phone = new AM.Data.Models.PhoneNumber()
                    {
                        PhoneTypeId = request.PhoneTypeId,
                        DialNumber = request.DialNumber,
                        ApplicantId = request.ApplicantId,
                    };
                    await _db.PhoneNumbers.AddAsync(phone, cancellationToken);
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
                    response.PhoneNumberId = phone.PhoneNumberId;
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
 
    }
    #endregion
};
```

### How do I find out where `_mediator.Send(request)` is going, and how do I fix it to go to the right spot?

Comment: What happens if you break on the `_mediator.Send` line, and set into the code from there? It should take you to the method it is executing

Comment: Small nitpick: you are validating `long`s and `int`s with `NotNull()` when they are not nullable and will be set to 0 by ASP.NET Core binding engine if missing

Comment: @DavidG - Visual Studio doesn't step into anything. If that line is Yellow and I press F11 (Step Into), it goes straight to the next line like it didn't execute anything.

Comment: @MateusZampol - thanks! I fixed that in my code, but it did not fix the problem. I'll update my code here to display what I have on my PC.

Comment: When are you invoking the Validators? And why do you have 3 different ones?

Comment: @MateusZampol - the validators were written by other members of our team that handle validation. If you see errors, I can fix them, but as the junior developer on the group, I would need to provide a good reason if I change or delete them.

Comment: Please debug your code with breakpoints in the request handler and the pipeline behaviors.